# Mostrar un AlertDialog con resultado de una operacion matematica

Tags: android, alertdialog, fragment

Estoy haciendo una aplicación donde solo existe una Activity principal y sobre ella se muestran diferentes Fragments con operaciones matematicas.

Me gustaria que el resultado se mostrara en un AlertDialog y no en un TextView que es como lo tengo. Dejo el codigo para ver si alguien puede echarme una mano. Gracias.

**CODIGO:**

```
public class AnguloFragment extends Fragment {

    EditText edtText1, edtText2;
    Button ebtn1;
    TextView txtResultado;



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.angulo_fragment, container, false);


        edtText1 = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        edtText2 = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        ebtn1 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        txtResultado = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textResultado);
        ebtn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                double dR = Double.parseDouble(edtText1.getText().toString());
                double aN = Double.parseDouble(edtText2.getText().toString());
                double aN2 = aN * 2.0 * Math.PI/360.0;
                double aN3 = Math.cos(aN2);
                double dC = dR * aN3;
                //redondea resultado mostrando solo 2 decimales
                DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
                String sPi = df.format(dC);

                txtResultado.setText("DISTANCIA CORREGIDA "+sPi+" metros" );



            }


        });


        return rootView;

    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        getActivity().setTitle("Angulo de situacion");

    }





}
```

Comment: Hola @IvanBotero, fijate que acabo de de editar mi respuesta para decirte dónde va el código. Tal vez te convenga pasar por la sección de ayuda para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, pero básicamente, si tenés dudas sobre una respuesta, publicás un comentario sobre esa respuesta. Luego, si esa respuesta te sirvió, la marcás como aceptada, así nadie más intenta ayudar en un problema que está solucionado. Si algo no quedó claro, no dudes en escribir un comentario en mi repuesta. Saludos!

Comment: Gracias no me había dado cuenta.

Comment: Perdón @IvanBotero, no te entiendo de qué estás hablando.

Comment: @malvarez Has realizado un comentario en esta publicacion `fijate que acabo de de editar mi respuesta para decirte dónde va el código....` en donde me nombras

Comment: Disculpame @IvanBotero, no sé de dónde saqué tu nombre. Eso iba dirigido a Victor.

Comment: @malvarez Vale, recuerda que puedes editar el comentario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pongo el código con el que lo he conseguido:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Resultado");  //define el título
            builder.setMessage("Distancia corregida: "+ spi);

            builder.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            builder.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Básicamente:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
.setTitle("Respuesta")
.setMessage("El resultado es...")
.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
        // acá lo que tiene que hacer al hacer click en OK, fijate que podés personalizar el mensaje cambiando lo que dice aca: android.R.string.yes
    }
})
.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
        // acá lo que tiene que hacer al hacer click en NO, fijate que podés personalizar el mensaje cambiando lo que dice aca: android.R.string.yes
    }
})
.show();
```

Podés explorar las opciones, también hay un botón neutro, etc. Si querés definir un layout personalizado, también se puede. Y fijate que todos los métodos son opcionales, sólo con `new AlertDialog.Builder(context).show()` se muestra un Dialog.

Este código va en el lugar en el que querés desplegar el Dialog. En tu caso, en lugar de `txtResultado.setText("DISTANCIA CORREGIDA "+sPi+" metros" );`

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración, lo que me pasa ahora es que se me cierra la aplicación al pulsar el botón de calcular... a que podría deberse?

Comment: Deberías pegar el stacktrace junto con cómo quedó el código para ver cuál podría ser la causa

Comment: Ya lo he solucionado modificando un poco el código, gracias me a servido de mucho tu ayuda.